# Modprobe error while trying to install PCAN driver on Ubuntu 1804

Tags: linux, driver, ubuntu-18.04

The error looks as follows.

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'pcan': Operation not permitted
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:979 command_do() Error running install command for pcan
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'pcan': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you are in secure boot enabled. You can confirm this by:

```
sudo apt-get install mokutil
mokutil --sb-state
```

If this gives you `SecureBoot enabled`, then get into the BIOS and disable secure boot of EFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just recompiling peak can and reinstall

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).